# wordpress after migration social icons doesn't shown only empty circles and some images doesn't shown

Tags: wordpress

I migrate wordpress version 5.2 from host to another one using all in one wp migration plugin.
firstly I installed new wordpress on the new host with latest version
afterthat I use th plugin to import exported file from old host all thing is goes well except
social icons and some images when inspect in page I saw

```
 <i class="fafa-facebook"></i>
```

and it should be  `<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>`
and `<imgclass="review__photo-img">`
and it should be `<img class="review__photo-img">` so how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using find and replace to correct both of these instances, the issue with this approach is that you'll need to manually identify the errors to correct.

Depending what IDE you're using this should be an relatively easy task, below is a how this can be done with VS code:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_find-and-replace

Comment: the source code is on remote server that doesn't have gui or editors

Comment: Do you have FTP access?

Comment: Then you can download the files, search and replace errors and then upload again